# Wordpress; if user exists auto change username

Tags: wordpress

I am coding a custom register page for my wordpress site. I am actually hiding the WP registering/member function a bit. This means that people fill in their info, automatically a username is created (combination first + lastname), auto a password is created, and people get logged in automatically. No confirmation e-mail is sent, so people are not aware that they actually created an account and are logged in. Now i have 2 questions:

- I was wondering if it would be possible that if a username already exists, people get logged in automatically, for instance by updating all the fields (including password) and log in the user.
- If that is not possible (I guess it is not); would it be possible that when the username exists, automatically the username is changed to a combination of: firstname, lastname+number. So: Peter Hanks, Peter Hanks 1, Peter hanks 2 etc. when a username exists?

Hope someone can help me out on this.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the password with wp_set_password
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password

After that, you can auto login with wp_signon
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon

Example (Not tested)

```
wp_set_password($new_password);

$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $username;
$creds['user_password'] = $new_password;

wp_signon( $creds, false );
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually did work, with the following code:
`$user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
wp_set_password($random_password, $user->id);

$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $username;
$creds['user_password'] = $random_password;

wp_signon( $creds, false );`
in combination with this custom registration code: http://www.tutorialstag.com/create-custom-wordpress-registration-page.html